# How could I get an editor to align vertically by a single character in selected text?

Tags: alignment, edit, geany

Let's say I've got a document (it happens to be a BibTeX file) filled with thousands of entries like this:

```
@article{hierarchy_problem_1,
    title = {Dynamics of spontaneous symmetry breaking in the Weinberg-Salam theory},
    author = {Susskind, Leonard},
    journal = {Physical Review D},
    volume = {20},
    number = {10},
    pages = {2619--2625},
    year = {1979},
    month = {November},
    publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
```

I want to be able to select one of those, or maybe a bunch of them, and get them to change to be aligned vertically by a single character, in this case the "=" character, so it becomes something like this:

```
@article{hierarchy_problem_1,
    title                = {Dynamics of spontaneous symmetry breaking in the Weinberg-Salam theory},
    author               = {Susskind, Leonard},
    journal              = {Physical Review D},
    volume               = {20},
    number               = {10},
    pages                = {2619--2625},
    year                 = {1979},
    month                = {November},
    publisher            = {American Physical Society}
}
```

My editor of choice is Geany just now (which has the facility to send selected text to some external, custom command -- context menu > Format > Send Selection to) but I will entertain anything. Bearing in mind that some titles of the papers can contain the "=" character, what might be a good way to do this? I would suspect at least that the "=" character in a line after some text like "journal", would be the *first instance* of that character, and then it gets spaces (I'd prefer to avoid tabs) added before it in order for it to end up at, say, the 30th column. What might be some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a shell/regex expert can build a script used in a custom command.

Personally, in your situation I will :

1. Set tabulation to `<tab>` in the document
2. *search & replace* `=` by `<tab><tab><tab><…>=`
3. Adjust distance with a [vertical selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033889/6709630) (need the plugin [Extra Selection](https://plugins.geany.org/geanyextrasel.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has an align to clipboard character.